# Sending data between two views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, routes

I have 10 item in my home page now i select the first item which id is 1.Then after i clicking this i am navigating to the second page .I want to Send this id to the second page but i am not able to do that .I am nobs at codeigniter framework.I have tried several technique but all fail.And also what is the best technique to do this job? Is there any way to do this things through anchor tag?

```
echo anchor('/my_de/'.$de_name.'/'.$id, $de_name);
```

I have also tried to fetch data using get but that doesn't work for me .Because here i am not using any kind of form tag.

Comment: What were the techniques you tried? Why didn't they work? What were the errors? What is wrong with using the `anchor()` you posted?

Comment: how to get the data form this tag? I want to get the $id .. but the actual link is set to  /my_de/(:any) in the route

Comment: `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);` would be my guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('controllerName/functionName/'. $param1.'/'.$param2); ?>"></a>`

and function in controller

`functionName($param1, $param2){...}`

**PS**: I would recommend user guide of codeigniter.